# Why does `std::function` can accept pointer to member function while the first param of `Args...` is passed by value?

Tags: c++

Suppose we have a class `Foo` as follows:

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    int x = 100;
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Obviously we can use `std::function` to wrap `Foo::print` as follows:

```cpp
std::function<void(Foo*)> f(&Foo::print);
Foo bar;
f(&bar);             // Output 100

// or

std::function<void(Foo&)> f(&Foo::print);
Foo bar;
f(bar);              // Output 100
```

But once I found that use `std::function<void(Foo)>` instead of `std::function<void(Foo*)>` or `std::function<void(Foo&)>` still works:

```cpp
// Neither Foo& nor Foo*

std::function<void(Foo)> f(&Foo::print);
Foo bar;
f(bar);              // Still output 100
```

Why does the last one works?

Answer (score 1):

Member functions require a specific class object to invoke, and `void(Foo)` is just a function type that accepts a copy of the `Foo` class.

So `f(bar)` will *copy* `bar` and invoke the `print()` member function of its copy. If `Foo` is not copyable then it won't work.